# SQL Server 2008 R2 insert into query error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

When I execute this query

```
create table Customer 
(
    customerid int, 
    customername varchar(20),
    ContactName varchar(15), 
    Address varchar(25),
    City char(10),
    Postalcode int, 
    Country varchar(15)
)

select * 
from Customer

insert into Customer(customerid, customername, ContactName, Address, City, Postalcode, Country)
values (4, 'Antonio Moreno', 'Taquería', 'Mataderos', 'México D.F.', '05023', 'Mexico')
```

I get an error

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 1
>   String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.

Comment: `México D.F.` is 11 characters long; your City definition allows for 10.  Also, it really should be `nvarchar` instead of `char`

Comment: This is just wrong. You have to word the question at least, and tell us what you have tried. The city name is longer than 10 characters 'México D.F.'

Answer (score 0):

The given "City" value is more than 10 characters, either you have to reduce your city value within 10 characters or you have to extend the datatype size like char(20)

Answer (score 0):

Change your `City` column to fix length:

```
ALTER TABLE Customer ALTER COLUMN City Varchar(20)
```

-- put `varchar(20)` instead `char(10)`, because SQL with varchar will store enough bytes as effective length of string, while char datatype will add spaces at the end of string if string is smaller then specified length.

then place your insert clause:

```
insert into Customer(customerid, customername, ContactName, Address, City, Postalcode, Country)
values (4, 'Antonio Moreno', 'Taquería', 'Mataderos', 'México D.F.', '05023', 'Mexico')
```